# return a string of comma delimited numbers from a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I return a comma delimited string using SQL Server?

```
select ID, 
(<<SomeQuery from TableB B where (B.Id = A.TableBId)>>)
from TableA A
```

and have it return results like:

```
1, '11, 12'
2, '22, 33'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use STUFF(), [See Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cb28/2)

```
SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(data AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM B 
         WHERE TableBId = A.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Comma_Output
FROM A
GROUP BY ID
```